# Where are the screenshots saved to for space engineers

Tags: space-engineers

I have taken a couple of screenshots on space engineers and I can't seem to find them. I have check both the local files and steam screen shots and can't seem to find them anywhere. Does anyone have any idea where these screen shots are saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 7, if you're having difficulty finding the folders using the method as shown above, you can use:

Start → Run →  type `%appdata%/SpaceEngineers` → open the "Screenshots" folder.

Easier to copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) & Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) this into the **Run** text box:

`%appdata%/SpaceEngineers`

Answer (score 0):

Mine C:\Users[YourWindowsUsernameHere]\AppData\Roaming\SpaceEngineers\Screenshots was empty, so I looked up the one from F12 steam feature.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\91169701\760\remote\244850\screenshots

91169701 might be different for you.

Answer (score -1):

The screenshots are stored in the following location:

`C:\Users\[YourWindowsUsernameHere]\AppData\Roaming\SpaceEngineers\Screenshots`

Answer (score -4):

Game saves are stored in

`C:\Users\[YourWindowsUsernameHere]\AppData\Roaming\SpaceEngineers\Screenshots`

Comment: Thanks, but this answer has already been posted.